# Do we need a canonical question about cron setup on the Pi?

Tags: discussion

I've just read another question that was the result of the Poster's erroneous assumption that "cron = pi" in terms of path, permissions, etc. Seems we get that once or twice a week. Would it be of any value to post up a "model Q&A" wherein this was explained clearly, and could be used as a standard reply to such questions?

Comment: In this case, to make it "broad enough" (as Aurora wrote), something like "How can I schedule an event with cron?" should be good.  This way you can give examples of at boot, etc., and discuss system vs. user cron files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a "canonical question" which can be used to solve multiple others is a great idea, and encouraged on all Stack Exchange sites.

The trick is to write a question that would be valid on its own but broad enough that it can help multiple people in future — easier said than done, sometimes — but in this specific case, I think it's possible.

You can post a self-answered question if you want, too; that'll probably make your intentions clear that you're not *personally* looking for help, but hoping to help other people.

Once your canonical is established, you can flag other questions as duplicate to point questioners in the right direction. You can see some of the most [frequently linked questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) for inspiration on how to get it right.